# Visual studio enterprise 2019 creating java project

Tags: java, visual-studio

In visual studio 2019 enterprise create new project window I see `java` in the languages drop down. However it doesn't list any project templates.

[image: create new project window]

When I click on install more tools and features, it redirects me to visual studio installer. In Visual studio installer, can't find any options to install Java.

Is there any extension which can be installed in Visual Studio enterprise 2019, to enable Java development?

Comment: It is same under Visual Studio Community 2019. In options under installation there is OpenJDK, but nothing changed after installing it.

Answer (score -2):

You can self install it with this link
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java

Check out the getting started for a step by step installation. Its got gif's and all. Personally I use intelliJ for Java and visual with C and C++. IntelliJ also has a community free version. 
(would have posted as a comment but need 50 pts apparently to do this).

Comment: That's for Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio - they're very different products.

Comment: This link is for visual studio code. Its not for visual studio enterprise 2019.